# What does " cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" mean?

Tags: c, factorial

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, fact = 1, n;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact = fact * i;
        
    }
    printf("%d\n", fact);
    return 0;
   
}
```

#### After running fine once , the next time Irun it shows this problem

```
PS D:\Programming\c programming\11a factoril> gcc 1a-facorial.c
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file a.exe: Permission 
denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

please enswer this  problem

Comment: It seems like `a.exe` is running in the background. You have to kill it first before executing it again.

Comment: @RohanBari How can I kill it...?

Comment: Go to the Task Manager, find the process, and **End Task** it.

Comment: How do you start the program? What input do you give it? Do you get a correct print of the result?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Gets the print  right the frist time.But next time this problem shows...

Comment: Do note that you need to compile between runs only if you have changed the source code and want to see the effects of that, or if the executable was removed.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the file `a.exe` exists and it is protected either because its access rights (or the ones of its directory) are bad (no write) or the file is locked (probaby because it is already used - system prevent its overwriting because it is running or something like that).

You can try to generate an alternate executable by enforcing its name: `gcc -o executable_name source_file.c` and see if the problem is the same. If no problem then one of the previous condition occurs and you will need to correct it.